# Reading data from text file to struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

What is wrong with the following code? How can I correct it?

Data is in rows seperated by commas: name, address, idnumber, age.

What I want is to read from a text file the above four fields, separated by commas in one line, and to store those data in the array struct given below in code as a instance of `struct person`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// struct person with 4 fields
    struct person
    {
        char name[100];
        char address[100];
        char IDnumber[20];
        int  age;
    };

int main()
{
   FILE *file = fopen ("personout.txt","r");
   // declares an struct array to store data
   struct person student[10];

   int k=0;

   if ( file != NULL )    
   {
       char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
       while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
       {
           // Returns first token
           char* token = strtok(line,",");

          // Keep printing tokens while one of the
          // delimiters present in str[].
          while (token != NULL) {
              k=0;
           // countword++;
              printf("%s\n", token);

              switch (k) {
              case '1':
                  student[k].name==token;
              case '2':
                  student[k].address==token;
              case '3':
                  student[k].IDnumber==token;
              case'4':
                  student[k].age==token;
              default:
                  break;
              }

              k++;

              // put the values to array
              token = strtok(NULL, ",");
          }
      }
      printf("%s\n", student[k].name);
      fclose ( file );
  }

}
```

Comment: replace the `==` by `=` in your switch, == is to check if its equal and = is to assign a value. if this doesnt solve your problem, please show us what output you get in your program.

Comment: Add some `break`s to your cases. and remove the quotes from the case labels. Plus: you are abusing `k` here. `student[k].name==token;` is not an assignment.